# How to create AutoCAD Layers using windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocad-plugin

I'm working on creating a windows form plugin to create Layers from the user selected items on my windows form.

I am reading a list of Layers in to a list box(lbGetLayers), a list of modifiers in to another listbox(lbModifyer) from two different csv files. Additionally, I have created two classes to hold the layer, modifier objects.

**Goal:** is to create a new layer with the correct Name, Color, Line Style, and Line Weight based on user selected items.

**Issue:**
I am trying to write a function to build the logic before creating the layer to satisfy the below two conditions:

1) Layer- Will have a color, line style, and line weight. Let the user pick 1 or more. If the user picks more than 1 then the app will create all layers selected.

2)Modifier – will override the color, line style, and line weight. The user can pick 0 or 1.

3)Status(Edited) - will again override the color, line style and the line weight. The user can pick 0 or 1.

I came up with the a function which is not appropriate to satisfy these conditions. 
I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me solving this problem.

Thanks!!

**BuildLayers:**

```
  public Intellayer Buildlayer()
{
    //can select Layer - 1 or more 
    //Get Selected Layer Object - color, line style & line weight
       foreach(Intellayer SelectedLayer in lbGetLayers.Items)
       {
            foreach (Modifyer SelectedModifyer in lbModifyer.Items)
            { 
                if(lbGetLayers.SelectedItems.Count > 1 || lbModifyer.SelectedItems.Count <= 1)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SelectedLayer.layername + "-" + SelectedModifyer.name);
            }
        }
```

**Class:**

```
public class layer
    {
       public string disciplane { get; set; }  
       public string layername { get; set; }
       public string Linetype { get; set; }
       public int? Layercolor { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string Lineweight { get; set; }
       public override string ToString()
        {
            return layername;
        }
    }

 public class Modifyer
    {
        public string discipline { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int? color { get; set; }
        public string Linetype {get;set;}
        public string Lineweight { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

**Edited:**

**BuildLayers:**

```
 public List<layer> Buildlayers()
        {
            //Build selected layers

            List<layer> Getselectedlayers = null;//list of selected layers
            if (lbGetLayers.SelectedItems.Count >= 1) 
            {
                    Getselectedlayers = new List<layer>();
                    Getselectedlayers.AddRange(lbGetLayers.SelectedItems.Cast<layer>());
                    foreach (layer lname in Getselectedlayers)
                    {
                        lbGetLayers.SelectedItems.Cast<layer>();
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lname.Linetype + "," + lname.Lineweight + "," + lname.Layercolor);
                     }
                if (lbModifyer.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    Modifyer modifyer = (Modifyer)lbModifyer.SelectedItem;
                    foreach (layer lname in Getselectedlayers)
                    {
                        lname.Override(modifyer);//Override with Modifyers
                    }
                }
                if(lbStatus.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                     Status status = (Status)lbStatus.SelectedItem;
                    foreach (layer lname in Getselectedlayers)
                    {
                        lname.Override(status);//Override with Status
                    }
                }
            }
            return Getselectedlayers;//return list of selected layers
        }       
        }
    }
```

**Class:**

```
 public class layer
        {
           public string disciplane { get; set; }  
           public string layername { get; set; }
           public string Linetype { get; set; }
           public int? Layercolor { get; set; }
           public string Description { get; set; }
           public string Lineweight { get; set; }

            public layer Override(Modifyer modifyer)
            {
                layer newLayer = new layer();
                newLayer.layername = this.layername;
                newLayer.Layercolor = modifyer.color;
                newLayer.Linetype = modifyer.Linetype;
                newLayer.Lineweight = modifyer.Lineweight;
                return newLayer;
            }
           public layer Override(Status status)
            {
                layer newlayer = new layer();
                newlayer.layername = this.layername;
                newlayer.Layercolor = status.color;
                newlayer.Linetype = status.Linetype;
                newlayer.Lineweight = status.Lineweight;
                return newlayer;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return layername;
            }
        }
```

Comment: **Please do not ever change a question like this.** It makes the accepted answer completely nonsensical, and any future readers will be scratching their heads as to how that is the accepted answer. At the very least, place it below your original post with an **EDIT** header so that the question and answer still make sense. _But really, this should have been a new question._ I can see your problem clearly, but I am not changing my answer completely as that is a massive waste of my time! Please fix your question as I suggested, and I will add an edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: [This thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted) may be  worth a read.

Comment: @Nik, As suggested, I have edited the code to its original post. Kindly, excuse me for my mistake. I will keep your suggestions for future posts. Thank you.

Comment: Upon further reflection, your code has a number of issues, and it is best that you ask a new question if you really want a good answer. Please see [this question and answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/7159784). I would imagine that you will get a solution from someone within minutes. If not the case, let me know and I will answer it. Answering your follow-up question here really takes away from the original question, and makes it not very useful for future readers.

Comment: @Nik, I understand your view on this issue. Additionally, I have been stuck with this Issue since a week and could not able to proceed. Thought your previous answer would work and it did work for an extent but I am unable to override the values as per the question. Thought to bring back this issue back to you as you have already suggested an answer before. I would appreciate if you could help answering it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have most of the meat there, but there are a couple issues in the code you posted aside from the logic inside the `Buildlayer()` method.

Let's start with the constructor. The point of the constructor is to initialize the form. This is also a good place to assign data to your controls. Here, the user has not had a chance to select any items as the forms is not yet visible. This is where you should be parsing your CSV file and assigning the resulting objects to your respective listboxes.

```
public LayerCreationTool()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fillListBoxes();
}

private void fillListBoxes()
{
    //get layers from CSV here and put them into ListBox
    lbGetLayers.Items.AddRange(getLayersFromCSV().ToArray());
    lbModifyer.Items.AddRange(getModifiersFromCSV().ToArray());
}

private List<layer> getLayersFromCSV()
{
    List<layer> layers = new List<layer>();
    //...Do your parsing here;
    return layers;
}

private List<Modifier> getModifiersFromCSV()
{
    List<Modifier> modifiers = new List<Modifier>();
    //...Do your parsing here;
    return modifiers;
}
```

I also added a method `Override()` to your `layer` class. This will allow you to easily utilize your modifier.

```
public class layer
{
    public string layername { get; set; }
    public string Linetype { get; set; }
    public int? Layercolor { get; set; }
    public string Lineweight { get; set; }

    public layer Override(Modifier modifier)
    {
        layer newLayer = new layer();
        newLayer.layername = this.layername;
        newLayer.Layercolor = modifier.color;
        newLayer.Linetype = modifier.Linetype;
        newLayer.Lineweight = modifier.Lineweight;
        return newLayer;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return layername;
    }
}
```

Now that you have a functional form, you need a way for the user to say "Go". I've taken the liberty of adding a button to the form, and in the click event of the button is where you should be creating your layers as per your logic. Also, Since you want to be returning more than one layer, `Buildlayers()` should return `List<layer>` rather than `layer`.

The idea for the logic is simple: if a modifier is NOT selected, then add all the selected layers to add to AutoCad. If a modifier IS selected, then use the `Override()` method to grab and modify all selected items one at a time.

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<layer> layersToAddToAutoCad = Buildlayers();
    //now use your these layers to add to AutoCad...
}

//You need to return a List of layers that you then use
//to add layers to AutoCad
public List<layer> Buildlayers()
{
    List<layer> ret = null;

    if(lbGetLayers.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ret  = new List<layer>();
        //if no modifier selected, great, just grab all the selected layers
        if (lbModifyer.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            ret.AddRange(lbGetLayers.SelectedItems.Cast<layer>());
        }
        else
        {
            Modifier modifier = (Modifier)lbModifyer.SelectedItem;
            foreach (layer layerToAdd in lbGetLayers.SelectedItems)
            {
                ret.Add(layerToAdd.Override(modifier));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;//method must return something.
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks alot. Additionally, I have added a new condition i.e. State– will again override the color, line style, line weight. The user can pick 0 or 1. Do I have to update the Layer class with the override method(State state) ?  and update the Build Layer function()? Kindly, let me know about your thoughts on it. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. You can [overload](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) the `Override` method to take `State` OR `Modifier`. Change your `BuildLayers()`  accordingly, the logic should be the same as what I have in the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! Additionally, is there a way that I could get the selected items from two list boxes separated by "-" and display the complete string on the form?
 For example: if i select the item XXX from listbox 1 and item YYY from  listbox 2, i want to display the name of my project as "XXX-YYY" ? Kindly, let me know your thoughts on it.

Comment: As you have suggested, I have updated my Function and class for overriding the layer objects. But, For some reason, not able to override the values? Not sure, what's missing. Could you help me with this? Thanks.
Please see the updated code in the question.